SvelteKit fetch from static throws 500 on production
Im creating an sveltekit app that fetches json from /static/schemas/{param}.json
The schemas folder will contain hundreds of json files so I really dont want to import it.
Example route: http://localhost:5173/schema/test
[schema]/+page.server.js
export async function load({ fetch, params }) {
    const { schema } = params;
    const schemaFetch = await fetch(`/schemas/${schema}.json`);
    const json = await schemaFetch.json();
    return {json}
}

Locally http://localhost:5173/schema/test works like a charm, but when I deploy to prod I get 500.
Convox log:
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0 TypeError: fetch failed
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0     at fetch (file:///usr/src/app/build/shims.js:20346:13)
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0     at async fetch (file:///usr/src/app/build/server/index.js:3641:18) {
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0   cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0       at onConnectTimeout (file:///usr/src/app/build/shims.js:7301:26)
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0       at file:///usr/src/app/build/shims.js:7248:46
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0       at Immediate._onImmediate (file:///usr/src/app/build/shims.js:7289:9)
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0       at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0     code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0   }
2024-05-21T08:14:47Z service/web/0b8d8e2753d9443e90d44e6247b9dfb0 }

Note: If I try to fetch a non-existing json file, i get error 404.
Any help is deeply appreciated!!
Im using convox for production, and @sveltejs/adapter-node

After you have deployed, can you open one of the JSON files directly in your web browser? Also, it's not relevant to your problem (I think), but when you send a GET request, it makes no sense to add the Content-Type header to it, since GET requests have no body.

Yes, mysite.org/schemas/test.json works fine.
Aalso, thanks for the heads up on the header

Hmm... fetch() from SvelteKit does not seem to work as it should. Seems to be something related to the network. There is also a SvelteKit issue about it, but no solution :/ Don't know if there's anything you can do about it (I'm not good at networking), but maybe there are some options in Convox you can change (maybe force IP4 or IP6 to be used), or use another version of Node.js. Good luck, I'm out of here xD
